# verifying digital signature in c#

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have a signed "DLL" file that I want to validate his digital signature in run time ("Before I'm loading it")

I have the public key of the certificate embedded in my code,
Is there a way to get the "message digest" from the digital signature? or another way to validate the file hasn't manipulated?

I don't want to check the "CA" and other attributes of the certificate because a malicious user can create a certificate with the same attributes

*Note I don't want to user SignTool as well :)

Comment: it is possible, but through p/invoke and CryptoAPI unmanaged functions. You need to call `CryptQueryObject` function to get PKCS#7 object, then call `CryptGetMsgParam` to extract raw signature. And then use `SignedCms` .NET class to access managed signature.

Comment: Hi @CryptoGuy, can you give me an example code for that?

Thanks

Comment: Probably, yes. Later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some job for CryptoAPI and p/invoke (I don't know how to extract authenticode signature with .NET). Here is a code example of what I meant in my comment:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;

namespace CLRSignatures {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            IntPtr phCertStore = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr phMsg = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ppvContext = IntPtr.Zero;
            int pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType = 0;
            int pdwContentType = 0;
            int pdwFormatType = 0;
            if (!Crypt32.CryptQueryObject(
                Wincrypt.CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                args[0],
                Wincrypt.CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,
                Wincrypt.CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
                0,
                ref pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
                ref pdwContentType,
                ref pdwFormatType,
                ref phCertStore,
                ref phMsg,
                ref ppvContext
            )) {
                Console.WriteLine((new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())).Message);
                return;
            }
            int pcbData = 0;
            if (!Crypt32.CryptMsgGetParam(phMsg, Wincrypt.CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE, 0, null, ref pcbData)) {
                Console.WriteLine((new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())).Message);
                return;
            }
            byte[] pvData = new byte[pcbData];
            Crypt32.CryptMsgGetParam(phMsg, Wincrypt.CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE, 0, pvData, ref pcbData);
            var signedCms = new SignedCms();
            signedCms.Decode(pvData);
            try {
                signedCms.CheckSignature(false);
                Console.WriteLine("Signature check passed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            } finally {
                Crypt32.CryptMsgClose(phMsg);
                Crypt32.CertCloseStore(phCertStore, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    static class Wincrypt {
        // source type
        public const int CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE = 1;
        // object type
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CERT = 1;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CTL = 2;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CRL = 3;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_STORE = 4;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_CERT = 5;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_CTL = 6;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_CRL = 7;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED = 8;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_UNSIGNED = 9;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED = 10;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS10 = 11;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PFX = 12;
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CERT_PAIR = 13;

        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CERT = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CERT);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CTL = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CTL);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CRL = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CRL);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_STORE = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_STORE);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_CERT = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_CERT);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_CTL = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_CTL);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_CRL = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_SERIALIZED_CRL);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_UNSIGNED = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_UNSIGNED);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS10 = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS10);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PFX = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PFX);
        const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CERT_PAIR = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CERT_PAIR);
        public const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL =
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CERT |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CTL |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CRL |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_STORE |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_CERT |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_CTL |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_SERIALIZED_CRL |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_UNSIGNED |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS10 |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PFX |
            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CERT_PAIR;

        // format type
        const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY = 1;
        const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BASE64_ENCODED = 2;
        const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED = 3;
        const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY = 1 << CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY;
        const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BASE64_ENCODED = 1 << CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BASE64_ENCODED;
        const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED = 1 << CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED;
        public const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL =
            CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY |
            CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BASE64_ENCODED |
            CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED;

        public const int CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE = 29;

    }
    static class Crypt32 {

        [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptQueryObject(
            int dwObjectType,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            string pvObject,
            int dwExpectedContentTypeFlags,
            int dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags,
            int dwFlags,
            ref int pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
            ref int pdwContentType,
            ref int pdwFormatType,
            ref IntPtr phCertStore,
            ref IntPtr phMsg,
            ref IntPtr ppvContext
        );
        [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptMsgGetParam(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg,
            int dwParamType,
            int dwIndex,
            byte[] pvData,
            ref int pcbData
        );
        [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptMsgClose(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg
        );
        [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CertCloseStore(
            IntPtr hCertStore,
            int dwFlags
        );
    }
}
```

p.s. note that you have to reference `System.Security` assembly. `args[0]` receives the path to a DLL file.

Comment: Thank you very much! , But I want for example instead of: "signedCms.CheckSignature(false);" to check it with external public key / X509Certificate2.
The "CheckSignature"  method with X509Certificate2Collection doesn't seems to do the Job...

Comment: You can call `CheckSignature(false)` on required signature in the `SignerInfos` property. This property contains an array of signer information including public certificate.

Comment: But I want to check it with an external certificat,
This certificate is not include in the DLL
But has the same public key

Comment: I would suggest to use certificates attached to signature, because your certificate may produce different results.

Comment: But the whole resaon I want to do it is to validate that this file was signed by me.. For exmeple a user can create his own manipulate DLL and sign it by a certificate that he created. I want to validate that this DLL is signed by my my certificate.
I signed it by a certificate with a private key, and want to validate it with the public in my code , or in another file

Comment: did you see my last comment?

Comment: yes I see and still can't find a point. What you need is to find a signer info that matches your particular public key and run validation. You can't take your own certificate and check arbitrary signature with it.

Comment: you need to realize that signed content may have multiple signatures. Each signature has unique value and it can be properly decrypted only by using certificate associated with this particular signature. This is why you need to find appropriate signer info with matching public key.

Comment: But as a "malicious" user I can "hack" this validation by signed my file with a different certificate that has the same public key... thats pretty easy to do.
And you method is only validate that the signer that attach to the file can valid that he signed the file.... well yes he signed it and the digital signature is valid. But I didn't validate it with the real certificate.
Did you get my point of view?

Comment: you are incorrect, because private and public keys are strictly associated. Particular public key may have only one associated private key and vice versa. And if malicious user was able to generate signature that is validated with the same public key (as your), then malicious user has your private key. You are hacked.